# Have: Debian - Doesn't work: Internet - Need: make or automake

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, macbook, make, broadcom

I recently installed Debian Lenny 5.0.3 on a macbook (black, model 4,1). The system seems to work.

However, I found out that my ethernet port is not working (I have only used wireless so far), and getting my computer repaired for 6 months is currently not an option.... so I need to get my WiFi up and running!

I found a guide on how to do that [here](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43), but this assumes that I have acces to either synaptic (no internet) or make/automake, but (root)terminal says:

```
batman@debian:~$ make foo
bash: make: command not found
batman@debian:~$ automake bar
bash: automake: command not found
batman@debian:~$
```

So, long story short, I need to:

1. get make or automake using the internet on another computer, and then transfer with a usb stick *or*
2. get packages with apt-get / synaptic the same way.

My wireless card is a Broadcom Corporation BCM4328 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 03), by the way.

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Doing this via Sneakernet (eg, thumbdrive) is possible, but it won't be pretty.  Basically, you get to do Apt's job and search through http://packages.debian.org by hand for the packages you need (and all their dependencies).

   1. Start with searching by package name on the front page.  `make` is an easy one ([there's only one](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/make)).  Unfortunately, there are lots of `automake` packages ([automake](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/automake), [automake1.4](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/automake1.4), [automake1.7](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/automake1.7), [automake1.9](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/automake1.9) ...), and the package you're compiling may require a specific version.
   2. Go to the main page for each package, and find your architecture in the table at the bottom (i386, ia64, amd64, etc).  That links to a download page for the package.
   3. Repeat step 2 for any dependencies listed on the package page (the red dots) you don't already have, and any suggested packages you might need.
   4. Repeat step 3 for each dependency you downloaded.
2. You can do this with apt-get/synaptic on another Debian Lenny system (that *is* internet-capable) if you have one available.  Just use apt-get or Synaptic to install the packages you need on that system.  The downloaded packages are placed in *`/var/cache/apt/archives`* after installation.  Just:

   - Copy files from *`/var/cache/apt/archives`* onto your thumbdrive, and
   - Use `dpkg -i package.deb` to install the package files to the offline system.

Comment: This is definitely the answer to the question I asked! However, I'll try installing from a cd first - that seems easier..

Comment: note for option 2 (works with rescdsk's answer too): you can do this from a LiveCD, too; the packages won't get installed permanently, but will be available in the Apt cache until you shut the system down.  the apt-cross tool might even allow you to grab Debian packages from an Ubuntu LiveCD.  might be handy for one-off situations.

Answer (score 3):

You can install make (and other needed tools) from DVD.

Answer (score 2):

(was a recommendation for apt-zip, but upon further reflection, there's another package that's better:)

apt-cross might be appropriate for you, if you have another Debian system:  you tell it the architecture and suite (lenny), and it can download the appropriate packages for you.

http://packages.debian.org/lenny/apt-cross

Comment: Don't have another debian system